# Shadows distorted and enlarged upon rendering

Tags: rendering, materials, light

When I render the scene, the shadows of the fish have become distorted and enlarged. I have played around with the shadow settings on the meshes, materials, textures and environment but cannot fix the problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: scene and settings]

Comment: What happens when you have a flat ground mesh? I think the issue is that the ground mesh is warped.

Comment: @CharlesL Have just replaced the floor of the lake with a flat plane and got exactly the same result.

Comment: are you using a spotlight or a Sunlight? is it that you want to shadows not to be several times bigger than the  fish?

Comment: @Zeffii I am using a sunlight. yes that is exactly what I want

Comment: are the shadows OK when you hide the water?

Comment: @Zeffii if I remove the water from the render it is still the same

Comment: care to upload an image of without the water, it's easier to see the shadows. Also we have now eliminated the water being part of the problem (likely)

Comment: @Zeffii I do not know how to upload image in comments

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9440/discussion-between-zeffii-and-lindsey)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears from your image that you have two lamps lighting the scene. The properly sized shadows from your sun lamp *are* visible, but you also apparently have a spot lamp near the surface of the water, and that is causing the enlarged shadows. Look in the *Outliner* panel to make sure you have this spot lamp disabled.

[image]

[image]